# How to center multiple UI elements within a parent UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, subview

I'm trying to create these 6 UITextField centered within a UIVIew that I have centered and is 0.85 the width of `self.view`. I was able to get it working on one iPhone size however it was hardcoded and doesn't transform well on other iPhone sizes.

So now I'm trying to figure out the best way to properly center these 6 elements.

Here's what I currently have:

```swift
class FormView: UIViewController {
    //INSTANTIATING VARIABLES
    ...


    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        setupCodeFieldView()
    }
    
    private func setupCodeFieldView(){
        codeFieldView.backgroundColor = .green
        codeFieldView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        parentSubview.addSubview(codeFieldView)
        codeFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        codeFieldView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentSubview.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        //SETTING WIDTH SIZE AND CENTERING PARENT VIEW
        codeFieldView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85).isActive = true
        codeFieldView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        setupCodeFields()
    }

    fileprivate func setupCodeFields() {
        var textFieldArr: [UITextField] = []
        for index in 0...5{
            let field: UITextField = UITextField()
            field.returnKeyType = .next
            field.setUnderline()
            field.borderStyle = .none
            field.keyboardType = .numberPad
            field.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            field.tag = index
            field.textAlignment = .center
            let valueWidth = codeFieldView.bounds.size.width/6
            field.placeholder = String(describing: valueWidth)
            field.accessibilityIdentifier = "field" + String(index)
            codeFieldView.addSubview(field)
            field.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            field.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.45, green: 0.46, blue: 0.50, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
            field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            //HERE IS HOW SET THE WIDTH OF THE BUTTON
            field.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: floor(valueWidth)-5).isActive = true
            field.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
            field.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeFieldView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            if index == 0 {
                field.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:codeFieldView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
                
            } else {
                field.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldArr[index-1].rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
            }
            textFieldArr.append(field)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I currently have. You can see that the 6 elements' parent view is centered and that I'm struggling to have the 6 children UITextFields perfectly spaced across the highlighted green parent view.
[image]

Mockup of how I'd like my UI to look:
[image: Mockup on how I'd like my UI to look]

Comment: Ok this is getting me closer except now I'm having the last UITextField overcompensate its width to fit within the width of the UIStackView. I'm also setting the first UITextFIeld to be equal to the stack's leftAnchor

Comment: @frlzjosh There are actually two relevant attributes for you to set in order to have evenly sized/spaced elements inside the `UIStackView`.  The first is `Alignment`; the second is `Distribution`.  `Alignment` should be set to `Fill`, while `Distribution` should be set to `Fill Equally`.  Additionally, there's no need to set any constraints at all for elements inside the `UIStackView`:  the stack view will take care of that itself!  The only constraints that you'll have to set are the stack view's own width, height and x/y position.

Comment: @frlzjosh In my experience, it's much simpler to set up this kind of thing using the Interface Builder than it is programmatically (although it is of course a matter of preference).  If you do all the setup in Main.storyboard, there will also be less clutter inside your View Controller.  To address your other problem of it not scaling for different phone sizes, you can connect `IBOutlets` to your stack view element, and to its width and height constraints.  This will let you set the numerical values based on the size of the current device (continued)

Comment: for example, to keep the width of the `UIStackView` always equal to 0.85 * the device width.  The width and height of the `Safe Area` become available inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, e.g. `let screenWidth = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width`.  Then you can, for example, have `hStackWidth.constant = 0.85*screenWidth`, `hStackHeight.constant = 0.15*hStackWidth.constant`, and `hStack.spacing = 0.05 * 0.85 * screenWidth` to keep everything in proportion across different phone sizes.  `hStack`, `hStackWidth` and `hStackHeight` are your `IBOutlets` to the stack view and its w/h constraints

Comment: I have tested this approach on both the iPhone 12 simulator and the largest sized iPad simulator, and it appears the same as in your 'desired results' mockup in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `UIStackView`

Here's a quick example (based on your code):

```
class FormView: UIViewController {
    //INSTANTIATING VARIABLES
    //...
    
    let codeFieldView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        setupCodeFieldView()

    }
    
    private func setupCodeFieldView() {
        codeFieldView.backgroundColor = .green
        codeFieldView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // not clear what you're doing with "parentSubview"
        //  so let's just add it to the root view
        
        view.addSubview(codeFieldView)
        
        // always respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // height of 60
            codeFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            // 85% of the width
            codeFieldView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85),
            // centered vertically and horizontally
            codeFieldView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            codeFieldView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

        ])
        
        setupCodeFields()
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupCodeFields() {
        
        // let's add a stack view to codeFieldView
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        codeFieldView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain stack view to all 4 sides of code field view
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeFieldView.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeFieldView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeFieldView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codeFieldView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // now we add the text fields
        for index in 0...5 {
            let field: UITextField = UITextField()
            field.returnKeyType = .next
            //field.setUnderline()
            field.borderStyle = .none
            field.keyboardType = .numberPad
            field.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            field.tag = index
            field.textAlignment = .center
            field.accessibilityIdentifier = "field" + String(index)
            field.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            field.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.45, green: 0.46, blue: 0.50, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
            
            // add it to the stack view
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(field)
        }
        
    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

Your question didn't indicate how you want the UI to look on a wider device, so here's how that looks when the phone is rotated:

[image]